# Warnings with pointer using .cfg file

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-12.04, libconfig

I try to setup a c programm using the libconfig. There is example1.c:

```
int main() 
{   
  const char **channel;

  config_t config;

  config_init(&config);

  config_read_file(&config, "example.cfg");
     if( config_lookup_string(&config,"value.channel",&channel) == CONFIG_FALSE)  
     {
        printf("Failed to read fields\n");
        return 1;  
     }
       printf("argumente = %s\n", (char *)channel);
       return 0; 
}
```

and the example.cfg file

> value =  {    channel = "hello"; }

if I compile it

> **gcc example1.c -lconfig**

it says:

```
example1.c:39:3: Warning: delivery of arguments 3 from »config_lookup_string« of a incompatible pointer
/usr/include/libconfig.h:244:26: Detailed: »const char **« expected, but argument has typ »const char ***«
```

The funny thing is it works... the output is:
**argumente = hello**

How can I get rid of this warning ?

If I change the decleration to `const char *channel` and the output  `printf("argumente = %s\n", channel);`, I receive a segfault at start and a warning at compiling like ... `Detailed: »const char **« expected, but argument has typ »const char *«`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get rid of one `*` in your declaration of `channel`.  If you do that, you can also remove the cast in your `printf` call.

The reason it's "working" now is that cast is hiding a second warning about your `printf` format.  Your program is behaving just like the extra `*` was removed already - just in a confusing way.

Comment: changed to const char *channel; and at the end printf("argumente = %s\n", channel); but I still get Segfault when starting...

Comment: @Fendrix, you must have changed something else - there's no way you could get that error message given your original example.  How can it be expecting a `char *` one time and a `char **` another?